# Linearly independent derivatives

Tags: functional-analysis, smooth-functions

Let $f \in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R};\mathbb{R})$ be bounded and strictly monotonically increasing, whose $n^{th}$-derivative does not vanish *(except possibly, on a finite number of points)*.  Then, for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$, is the set of derivatives
$$
\left\{f^n\right\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}
$$
linearly independent?

Comment: This is a fairly novel remark, but notice that you must need to use both the boundedness and the strictly increasingness, since $e^x$ and $\cos x$ are examples of strictly increasing, and bounded, respectively, functions for which this doesn't hold. The answer will be interesting in any case.

Comment: Hint: if this was not the case, we would have $f^{(n)}=\sum_{0}^{n-1} a_k f^{(k)}$, that is a homogeneus differential equation with constant coefficients. Can you deduce some informations about $f$ from this?

Comment: Right!  Then its solution must be a (non-constant) exponential polynomial.  Whence, it must be unbounded (thus contradicting the assumption of boundedness)?

Comment: It is a complex exponential polynomial: thus its real part can look even as $\cos(x)$, which is bounded. The general solution will be a "mix" of those

Comment: In that case, I'm lost as to why the earlier comment offers a contradiction?

Comment: $\cos(x)$ is not increasing

Comment: Ah, I'm silly.  Ok thanks Gabriele! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proof by contradiction:
Let us suppose that there is a $n\in\mathbb{N}_0$ such that

$f^{(n+1)}=\sum_0^n a_k f^{(k)}$

This is a differential equation that is [linear homogeneus  with constant coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_differential_equation?wprov=sfla1). Its solution it's a linear combination of terms like
$x^ke^{ax}(\sin(bx)+\cos(bx))$, with $k\in \mathbb{N}, a,b\in\mathbb{R}$.

This contradicts either $f≠P(x)$ or $f$ being monotonous and/or bounded

Note: a nice example to the theorem is that $\arctan^{(n)}(x)$ is linearly independent. Knowing this one might ask: what is the span of this subset of $C^{\infty}$?

Comment: Actually, this is my next question.  Do you know of a result showing when the span is dense in the entire space $C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: @AIM_BLB I suppose Stone-Weierstrass could come useful, but my intuition tells me that it would be quite hard to obtain unbounded functions as limit of linear combination of those functions. Perhaps you might try to find some common property of linear combinations: maybe they are bounded?

Comment: True, I guess I'll have to give this some more thought